# Select only Facebook group posts which have attachments

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I can select posts and their authors from a particular Facebook group by doing:

```
    {"annonce_query":"SELECT post_id, actor_id, source_id, message, attachment  
    FROM stream WHERE source_id=MY_GROUP_ID LIMIT 10", 
"user_query":"SELECT uid, name, pic, profile_url FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #annonce_query)"}
```

This query fetches any posts, whether they have attachment or not. 
Is there any way to select only posts which have attachement of type image?
Thanks
Anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a way (There's always a way! :)).

You can do this by just checking the **Type** of the object attached with the post. As you can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream), the field `attachment.fb_object_type` specifies the type for the attachment. In case of image, this will be equals to *photo*.

So you can just add `WHERE attachment.fb_object_type = 'photo'` make sure that the attachment is an image.

Comment: Never thought it could be this easy. Thanks anyway